# How to change the height for Html.EditFor in Asp.net mvc.I've tried using jQuery .But failed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, html-helper

I've been working on asp.net mvc.I ran into a problem.I have a textbox which is multiline.I want to increase it's height.I've tried using @html.raw method and also tried to add inline style using new{styles:} in Html.EditFor.Nothing worked.So,How can I do that ?Here is my View

```
   @model CTCFremont.Models.eMail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#PrayerRequest").css("height", 300);
        $("#PrayerRequest").css("width", 200);

    });
</script>
<h2>Submit Your Prayer Request</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>eMail</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field"  >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request,Html.Id("PrayerRequest"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Let me know how to deal with this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which editor you want to use a textarea for, but just use code like the following to specify a height in CSS styles.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Request, new {@style = "height: 30px;"})
```

Comment: Thank You Todd.I've one more error during vaidating email email address.The email address is correct .But still I see that, 'the value '...@gmail.com' is invalid.I don't have any custom validations that has the statement 'The Invalid {0} is invalid'

Comment: Guessing your CTCFremont.Models.eMail.Email property has attributes like [Required] or [RegularExpression] or [StringLength]. If that's not it, there must be JavaScript doing that for you.

Comment: CTCFremont.Models.eMail----              [Required(ErrorMessage="Please print your Email")]
       [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,ErrorMessage="Enter a valid email address")]
       [Display(Name=" Your Email")]
       [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="enter a valid email address")]
       public string Email { get; set; }

Comment: Try removing the [DataType]. I think it's redundant to [EmailAddress].